retrieve response body from wget --method=PUT
I knwo that with GNU wget (https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) I can send PUT HTTP requests with --method=PUT, but I cannot figure out how to read the response body I get back.
What I've tried:
wget -S -o - --method=PUT --header="Content-Type: application/json" --body-file=tmpfile.txt "https://api.example.com/api/v1/path"

This prints the response code and headers, but not the body...
wget -o - -O - --method=PUT --header="Content-Type: application/json" --body-file=tmpfile.txt "https://api.example.com/api/v1/path"

I understand -o (lowercase) specifies a log location, and -O (uppercase) specifies a downloadfile location. But the downloadfile (or stdout) stays empty.
Is it possible to retrieve the whole response with --method=PUT ?
Which combination of options would I need?
P.S.: I know curl is the supperior tool for this, but I cannot use that in this script's environment.

fixed it, regardsless of the response code, the body data does show up in -O specified file when adding the  --content-on-error flag, i.e.
wget -o - --content-on-error -O - --method=PUT --header="Content-Type: application/json" --body-file=tmpfile.txt "https://api.example.com/api/v1/path"

With the PUT request, wget does not automatically save the response body to a file.To save the body, use:
wget --method=PUT --header="Content-Type: application/json" --body-file=tmpfile.txt "https://api.example.com/api/v1/path" -O response.txt


I tried this, that did not work in my case. What worked was also setting the --content-on-error flag. Even though my call returns with status 201 (created).
But thank you for taking the time to help!

@hedwig Ah, makes sense.  That would ensure that wget gives you the output, even if it doesn't return 0.
